# How to handle unused variable in js files eslint errors?

Tags: javascript, jslint, eslint

I have two different js files one is called alert.js

alert.js

```html
function alerts(){
alert('HI');
}
```

Another one is called draw.js

```html
function call_alert(){
 alerts();
}
```

Functionally its working well, but in validation using jslint or eslint shows me these errors:

- 'alerts' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)
  (this error for alert.js file)
- 'call_alert' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)
  (this error for draw.js file)

Comment: Well call `call_alert()` then.

Comment: alerts() method in alert.js file, call_alert() in draw.js file

Comment: scope of the code should be in a single file. Try to cocat using gulp and validate it.

Comment: You already answered your own question.

Comment: no i m not able to use single file..here i have sent small script..but my js function have above 1000 lines @Nirus

Comment: alert.js file have alerts() method...'alerts' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)  coming when i validate indvidually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have functions or variables that are defined in the global scope in one file but used in another, you can use [exported comments](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#exported) to tell ESLint that they're intended to be used elsewhere. (Note that this doesn't apply to Node.js or ES modules, which don't have global scope.)

```
/* exported alerts */
function alerts() {
    alert('HI');
}
```